# Get data in pie chart after click on column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have been working on charts, My requirement is when i click on column i want to display data in pie chart format. Initially its working good means i am getting static data in the column chart, But i want to display data in pie chart like circle. i will place code which is working good in column format. But i want it in pie format. Initially column should be in column format, When i click on any on the column data should be display in pie format.
Thanks in advance

```
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

            <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

        <script>
        // Create the chart
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
          chart: {
            type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Basic drilldown'
          },
          xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
          },

          legend: {
            enabled: false
          },

          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              borderWidth: 0,
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
              }
            }
          },

          series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
              name: 'Animals',
              y: 5,
              drilldown: 'animals'
            }, {
              name: 'Fruits',
              y: 2,
              drilldown: 'fruits'
            }, {
              name: 'Cars',
              y: 4,
              drilldown: 'cars'
            }]
          }],
          drilldown: {
            series: [{
              id: 'animals',
              data: [{
                  name: 'Mammals',
                  y: 4,
                  drilldown: 'mammals'
                },
                ['Reptiles', 2],
                ['Vertebrates', 1]
              ]
            },

            // trying to get data in pie chart after click on any of the column
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
              chart: {
            type: 'pie'
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Basic drilldown'
          },
          xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
          },

          legend: {
            enabled: false
          },

          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              borderWidth: 0,
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
              }
            }
          },

              id: 'mammals',
              data: [['Cats', 3], ['Dogs', 2], ['Platypus', 1]]   
         {
              id: 'mammals',
              data: [{
                  name: 'cats',
                  y: 4,
                  drilldown: 'cats'
                },
                ['one', 2],
                ['two', 1]
              ]
            },

                // third drill down
            {
              id: 'cats',
              data: [['Cats1', 3], ['Dogs1', 2], ['Platypus1', 1]]
            },{
              id: 'fruits',
              data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
              ]
            }, 
            },

            // end 
        {
              id: 'cars',
              data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
              ]
            }]
          }
        });
        </script>
// working good in column format
<script>
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Basic drilldown'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'Animals',
      y: 5,
      drilldown: 'animals'
    }, {
      name: 'Fruits',
      y: 2,
      drilldown: 'fruits'
    }, {
      name: 'Cars',
      y: 4,
      drilldown: 'cars'
    }]
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      id: 'animals',
      data: [{
          name: 'Mammals',
          y: 4,
          drilldown: 'mammals'
        },
        ['Reptiles', 2],
        ['Vertebrates', 1]
      ]
    },

    // second drill down
    {
      id: 'mammals',
      data: [['Cats', 3], ['Dogs', 2], ['Platypus', 1]]   
    }, {
      id: 'mammals',
      data: [{
          name: 'cats',
          y: 4,
          drilldown: 'cats'
        },
        ['one', 2],
        ['two', 1]
      ]
    },
    // third drill down
    {
      id: 'cats',
      data: [['Cats1', 3], ['Dogs1', 2], ['Platypus1', 1]]
    },{
      id: 'fruits',
      data: [
        ['Apples', 4],
        ['Oranges', 2]
      ]
    }, {
      id: 'cars',
      data: [
        ['Toyota', 4],
        ['Opel', 2],
        ['Volkswagen', 2]
      ]
    }]
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: iam using static data on click i want to display in pie format

Comment: In the most basic way, you can just do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/pqca9jn7/
Then you need to add separate axes for different drilldown levels, and ways to control what is visible.

Comment: it's working friend but, i want to apply click events in pie chart also. because in column chart i created three click events. how to apply same to it in pie also

Comment: You add clickevents on `drillUp` and `drillDown` as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/py8ons12/ . With more details here: [Highcharts API on events](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown)

Comment: let you know once i get in to fetch data from server side Thank you